# An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the ListBuckets operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I've launched an ec2 instance using Ansible and successfully ssh'd into it using the  playbook, I've also added 'AmazonS3FullAccess' IAM role to it, but when I'm trying to copy file from s3, I get an error:

```
"fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden"
```

This is the command I've used for copying the files:

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket-name/folder-name/file-name file-name
```

Also when I manually enter into the instance and try to list all the s3 buckets available to the instance, I get this error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the ListBuckets operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

Appreciate all the help!

Comment: Sounds like you have some placeholder default still configured, either in an environment variable or in .aws/credentials

Comment: .aws/credentials contains values for aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key, the values of these variables are working fine for connecting to the instance through local, but not working for s3

Comment: I meant on the instance itself - the credentials returned from instance metadata should not be invalid (maybe not have access, but not be unknown altogether), so my only explanation was that something in Ansible is misconfigured and sets its own credentials that are placeholders though, like aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id

Comment: Try running the `aws s3` command with the `--debug` option to gain insight in where the key comes from, and if that doesn't already pointed you towards the solution, include the output in the question please

Comment: so the thing is in .aws/credentials, the access_key_id and secret_access_key are old (credentials using which the instance was created) and a new one is needed everytime so maybe thatswhy its giving error, how can i get new vars in instance as well without having to manually change it everytime

Comment: If you remove the static credentials, the aws cli will automatically load them from instance metadata.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I figured out the problem, through the playbook I was changing the credentials automatically, so it wasn't working. I removed them and used the ones by default, and it's working fine now. Thank you Daniel and Cherry